# Battery and resistor symbols into a text

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages, physics

In this moment I have forgotten between many Physics books which I have read, where I have seen the *battery* and *resistance symbols* to use when I write a text, an article or a paragraph.

[image]

I just have found the *resistance symbol* in inline mode as into the image below, but for the *battery* there was a symbol similar to this image (without green background)

[image]

but without the signs, always into a phrase, one paragraph, between two words. Into other English Physics book I have found this:

[image]

which might be okay if it existed or in vertical on an horizontal position. I would also like to thank everyone for the English language adjustments and the tags.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=.6cm}
    \newcommand\esymbol[1]{\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [#1] (1,0); \end{circuitikz}}

    This is a battery \esymbol{battery1} and this is a resistor \esymbol{resistor}

\end{document}
```

**ANSWER2**
[image]

```
    \documentclass{minimal}

   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

   \begin{document}

    % Define a command for drawing dipole symbols with a bit of wire on 
    either end
    \newcommand\esymbol[1]{\tikz[circuit ee IEC] \draw (0,0) -- (.1,0) node 
     [#1,anchor=west,name=s] {} (s.east) -- +(.1,0);}

    This is a battery \esymbol{battery} 

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Very kind I not want use circuitikz package :-) although I have put like tags packages. I always appreciate the efforts of users and I vote positive for your answer. You're really funny. :-) There is the battery symbol that is too high and the wires are too long. The second symbol is good.

Comment: A lot of effort has been put into creating circuit symbols for tikz and circuitikz, but if you don want to use them  I seem to recall a package from MIT which predates TikZ..  OTOH, it seems MIT uses circuitikz these days.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Every answer for me it is always appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

These symbols are probably included in some package (beside `circuitikz`), but they are also fairly simple to construct from rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\resistor}{%
    \rule[3pt]{5pt}{.4pt}\hspace*{-.5pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{ 75}{\rule[4.5pt]{ 5pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{- 9pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-75}{\rule[4.5pt]{10pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{-.4pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{ 75}{\rule[4.5pt]{10pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{- 9pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-75}{\rule[4.5pt]{10pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{-.4pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{ 75}{\rule[4.5pt]{10pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{- 9pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-75}{\rule[4.5pt]{10pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{-.4pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{ 75}{\rule[4.5pt]{ 5pt}{.4pt}}\hspace*{-4.7pt}%
    \rule[3pt]{5pt}{.4pt}%
}
\newcommand{\battery}{%
    \rule[3pt]{6pt}{.4pt}%
    \rule{1pt}{6pt}\hspace*{1pt}%
    \rule[-1pt]{.5pt}{8pt}%
    \rule[3pt]{6pt}{.4pt}%
}
\begin{document}
The symbol of a resistor is \resistor{} and that of a battery is \battery.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also very kind Vincent....this morning I'm angry about school things outside of human logic and I can't remember where I saw it the symbol. Not in circuitikz but I remember it was another package. I thank you as js bibra for your kindness which I appreciate so cordially.